# eclipse rcp: why ViewerCell and ViewerRow do not have method to get row index?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

ViewerCell class has a method **`getColumnIndex`**, why not provide a method to return row index?
This really confuses me. Please give me some explanation about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `table.getItems().indexOf(cell.getElement())` (+/-).

The reason for this is found in virtual tables. For these you cannot easily find the row index...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here (extend TableViewer and add this method to your parent class):

```
public int getRowIndex(ViewerCell cell) {
    YourRowType row = (YourRowType) cell.getElement();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.doGetItemCount(); i++) {
        if (this.getElementAt(i).equals(row)) {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```